# US DS-160 photo upload issue

Tags: visas, usa

I have been trying to upload my picture in my US visa application but I keep getting this error: "Error: There was a missing or invalid parameter in the request" and I couldn't do anything beyond that.

Last night I was able to upload the photo but it didn't let me review and confirm it.

I'm worried as my US visa interview is tomorrow at 11:45AM.

What can I do now?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, im sorry i don't have an answer, but if it helps i think it is something which is system wide and nothing you're doing wrong. i assume this means you haven't been able to sign and submit you application?

Comment: Same here, "Error: There was a missing or invalid parameter in the request"

Comment: Im having the same issue. I've found some other forums and this seems to be a regular issue that resolves itself in time, the general advice seems to be 'just keep trying'.

Comment: same problem here. Same error message. hopefully they will fix their bugs by tomorrow?

Comment: Just as a precaution, take all digital documents with you on a memory stick, which contains nothing else.

Comment: Take an acceptable printed photo to the interview.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not the Department Of State help desk.

Comment: I would recommend reporting a website issue via https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/contact-us/report-website-issues.html

Comment: This question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate. The purported previous answer relates to a different error message.